# Encode into an `enumerate` environment

Tags: enumerate, latex-base

I am convinced that I need to encode lists that I have in various files in `enumerate` environments.  I have taken a sample of them and put them into one file, which I include in this post.

It looks like a multiple-choice test, except the number of choices in each problem is not the same.  The lower-case Roman numerals - i.), ii.), iii.) ... - for the choices should be typeset in bold, and the Arabic numerals for the problems should be typeset in bold.  Within each problem, I want the the right parenthesis of the lower-case Roman numerals to be aligned vertically in each column.  (I do get that from the following code.)  Between problems, I only want the the right parenthesis of the lower-case Roman numerals in the first column to be aligned vertically.  The Arabic numerals for the problems should be flush against the left margin.

From other code on this web site, I know that `label=\textbf{\roman{enumi}.)}` is used to typeset the lower-case Roman numerals. What is the option for the Arabic numerals to be typeset in bold?  I think the margins should be widened to accommodate the choices for one of the problems.

Should this be an  `enumerate` environment within an `enumerate` environment?  I have two `TikZ` environments in the code.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\setlength{\topmargin}{0.0in} \setlength{\textheight}{9in}

\begin{document}


\begin{center}\Large{\textbf{Review}}\end{center}\vskip0.3in



\noindent \textbf{1.) }Express the following decimals as fractions.
\begin{alignat*}{8}
{\mathrm{i.})} \ &1
\qquad \quad
&{\mathrm{ii.})} \ &0.25
\qquad \quad
&{\mathrm{iii.})} \ &0.025
\qquad \quad
&{\mathrm{iv.})} \ &0.0025 \\
{\mathrm{v.})} \ &0.125
\qquad \quad
&{\mathrm{vi.})} \ &0.0125
\qquad \quad
&{\mathrm{vii.})} \ &1.25
\qquad \quad
&{\mathrm{viii.})} \ &0.0625
\end{alignat*}
\vskip0.25in

\noindent \textbf{2.) }Express the following numbers as percents.
\begin{alignat*}{8}
{\mathrm{i.})} \ &\frac{1}{8}
\qquad \quad
&{\mathrm{ii.})} \ &\frac{1}{80}
\qquad \quad
&{\mathrm{iii.})} \ &\frac{1}{800}
\qquad \quad
&{\mathrm{iv.})} \ &1 \\
{\mathrm{v.})} \ &10
\qquad \quad
&{\mathrm{vi.})} \ &100
\qquad \quad
&{\mathrm{vii.})} \ &1.75
\qquad \quad
&{\mathrm{viii.})} \ &1.075
\end{alignat*}
\vskip0.25in


\noindent \textbf{3.) }$\triangle\mathit{ABC}$ is a right triangle, and its right angle is at $C$. $P$ is the foot of the altitude from $C$, and the lengths of $\overline{AP}$ and $\overline{BP}$ are 16 and 4, respectively. What is the length of $\overline{CP}$?
\begin{tabbing}
\hspace*{3em} \= \hspace{2.5in} \= \kill
\> {\textbf{a.) }}4             \> {\textbf{b.) }}$4\sqrt{2}$ \\
\> {\textbf{c.) }}$4\sqrt{3}$   \> {\textbf{d.) }}8 \\
\> {\textbf{e.) }}$8\sqrt{2}$
\end{tabbing}
\vskip0.2in

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}

%P is located at the origin and is the foot of the altitude of right triangle
%$\triangle{ABC}$ from C. The right angle of the triangle is at C.
\path (-4,0) coordinate (A) (0,0) coordinate (P) (1,0) coordinate (B) (0,2) coordinate (C);
\draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;

%The altitude from C is drawn.
\draw (P) -- (C);


%The labels for the vertices of $\triangle{ABC}$ are typeset.
\node[anchor=north, inner sep=0] at ($(A)!0.15cm!-90:(B)$){$A$};
\node[anchor=north, inner sep=0] at ($(B)!-0.15cm!-90:(A)$){$B$};
\node[anchor=south, inner sep=0] at ($(C) +(0,0.15)$){$C$};

\node[anchor=north, inner sep=0] at ($(P)!-0.15cm!(C)$){$P$};


%The lengths of AP and BP are labeled 16 and 4, respectively.
\node[anchor=south, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($($(A)!1.5mm!90:(P)$)!0.5!($(P)!1.5mm!-90:(A)$)$){$16$};
\node[anchor=south, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($($(B)!1.5mm!-90:(P)$)!0.5!($(P)!1.5mm!90:(B)$)$){$4$};


%A right-angle mark is drawn at P.
\coordinate (U) at ($(P)!3mm!45:(B)$);
\draw (U) -- ($(P)!(U)!(B)$);
\draw (U) -- ($(P)!(U)!(C)$);

%A right-angle mark is drawn at P.
\coordinate (V) at ($(C)!3mm!45:(A)$);
\draw (V) -- ($(C)!(V)!(A)$);
\draw (V) -- ($(C)!(V)!(B)$);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\vskip0.25in


\noindent \begin{minipage}[b]{4.65in}
\textbf{4.) }The area of a rectangle is 168 square inches, and its perimeter is 62 inches. What is the product of the magnitudes of its diagonals?
\begin{tabbing}
\hspace*{3em} \= \hspace{2.5in} \= \kill
\> {\textbf{a.) }}625   \> {\textbf{b.) }}300 \\
\> {\textbf{c.) }}200   \> {\textbf{d.) }}150 \\
\> {\textbf{e.) }}125
\end{tabbing}
\end{minipage}
%
%
%The baseline for the bounding box of the tikzpicture is by default "south."
\hspace{0.1cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}

%Vertices A, B, C, and D are located.
\path (0,0) coordinate (A) (20:{7/8}) coordinate (B) ($(B) +(110:3)$) coordinate (C) ($(C) +(-160:{7/8})$) coordinate (D);
\draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- cycle;

%The diagonals are drawn.
\draw[dashed] (A) -- (C);
\draw[dashed] (B) -- (D);


%The length and width of the rectangle are typeset.
\node[anchor={20+90}, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($($(A)!1.5mm!-90:(B)$)!0.5!($(B)!1.5mm!90:(A)$)$){$w$};
\node[anchor={110+90}, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($($(B)!1.5mm!-90:(C)$)!0.5!($(C)!1.5mm!90:(B)$)$){$\ell$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\vskip0.25in

\noindent \textbf{5.) }If $a - b = 1$, $b - c = 2$, and $c - a = d$, evaluate $d$.
\begin{tabbing}
\hspace*{3em} \= \hspace{2.5in} \= \kill
\> {\textbf{a.) }}$-3$  \> {\textbf{b.) }}$-1$ \\
\> {\textbf{c.) }}1     \> {\textbf{d.) }}3 \\
\> {\textbf{e.) }}4
\end{tabbing}
\vskip0.25in

\noindent \textbf{6.) }Evaluate the following logarithmic expressions.
\begin{alignat*}{6}
{\mathrm{i.})} \ &\log_{2}8
\qquad \quad
&{\mathrm{ii.})} \ &\log_{2}64
\qquad \quad
&{\mathrm{iii.})} \ &\log_{2}\frac{1}{8} \\
{\mathrm{iv.})} \ &\log 10
\qquad \quad
&{\mathrm{v.})} \ &\log 100
\qquad \quad
&{\mathrm{vii.})} \ &\log \left(\frac{1}{100}\right)
\end{alignat*}
\vskip0.25in


\noindent \textbf{7.) }Solve the following logarithmic equations.
\begin{alignat*}{6}
{\mathrm{i.})} \ &\log_{2}(3x + 7) = 3
\qquad \quad
&{\mathrm{ii.})} \ &2\log(x + 1) = 16
\qquad \quad
&{\mathrm{iii.})} \ &\log_{3}\left(\frac{x}{x - 4}\right) = 1 \\
{\mathrm{iv.})} \ &\log(x + 1) -  \log(x - 2) = 2
\qquad \quad
&{\mathrm{v.})} \ &\log\left(\frac{x + 1}{x - 2}\right) = 2
\end{alignat*}


\end{document}
```

Comment: have you tried the enumitem package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's something to get you started. I don't typeset math, really, so I don't want to definitively suggest that you should use `multicol` and `enumerate` over your `alignnat`, but it does seem to rely on a lot of manual, *ad hoc* code.  So what about this:

```
% We want multiple columns
\usepackage{multicol}
% We want to control our lists
\usepackage{enumitem}
% ... so, for first-level: numbers set flushleft, with a generous space between items, with the labels in bold
\setlist[enumerate,1]{% 
  leftmargin=*, itemsep=12pt, label={\textbf{\arabic*.)}}}
% For the second-level lists, we want roman numerals and a less generous space between items
\setlist[enumerate,2]{% (
  label={\textbf{\roman*.)}}, itemsep=8pt}
```

Putting it all together:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\setlength{\topmargin}{0.0in} \setlength{\textheight}{9in}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{% (
  leftmargin=*, itemsep=12pt, label={\textbf{\arabic*.)}}}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{% (
  label={\textbf{\roman*.)}}, itemsep=8pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}\Large{\textbf{Review}}\end{center}\vskip0.3in

\begin{enumerate}
\item Express the following decimals as fractions.
  \begin{multicols}{4}
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item 1
    \item 0.25
    \item 0.025
    \item 0.0025
    \item 0.125
    \item 0.0125
    \item 1.25
    \item 0.0625
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{multicols}

\item Express the following decimals as fractions
  \begin{multicols}{4}
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item $\frac{1}{8}$
    \item $\frac{1}{80}$
    \item $\frac{1}{800}$
    \item 1
    \item 10
    \item 100
    \item 1.75
    \item 1.075
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{multicols}

\item $\triangle\mathit{ABC}$ is a right triangle, and its right angle
  is at $C$. $P$ is the foot of the altitude from $C$, and the lengths
  of $\overline{AP}$ and $\overline{BP}$ are 16 and 4,
  respectively. What is the length of $\overline{CP}$?

  \begin{multicols}{2}
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item 4
    \item $4\sqrt{2}$
    \item $4\sqrt{3}$
    \item 8
    \item $8\sqrt{2}$
    \end{enumerate}

%\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}

    % P is located at the origin and is the foot of the altitude of
    % right triangle $\triangle{ABC}$ from C. The right angle of the
    % triangle is at C.
    \path (-4,0) coordinate (A) (0,0) coordinate (P) (1,0) coordinate
    (B) (0,2) coordinate (C); \draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;

    % The altitude from C is drawn.
    \draw (P) -- (C);


    % The labels for the vertices of $\triangle{ABC}$ are typeset.
    \node[anchor=north, inner sep=0] at ($(A)!0.15cm!-90:(B)$){$A$};
    \node[anchor=north, inner sep=0] at ($(B)!-0.15cm!-90:(A)$){$B$};
    \node[anchor=south, inner sep=0] at ($(C) +(0,0.15)$){$C$};

    \node[anchor=north, inner sep=0] at ($(P)!-0.15cm!(C)$){$P$};


    % The lengths of AP and BP are labeled 16 and 4, respectively.
    \node[anchor=south, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at
    ($($(A)!1.5mm!90:(P)$)!0.5!($(P)!1.5mm!-90:(A)$)$){$16$};
    \node[anchor=south, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at
    ($($(B)!1.5mm!-90:(P)$)!0.5!($(P)!1.5mm!90:(B)$)$){$4$};


    % A right-angle mark is drawn at P.
    \coordinate (U) at ($(P)!3mm!45:(B)$); \draw (U) --
    ($(P)!(U)!(B)$); \draw (U) -- ($(P)!(U)!(C)$);

    % A right-angle mark is drawn at P.
    \coordinate (V) at ($(C)!3mm!45:(A)$); \draw (V) --
    ($(C)!(V)!(A)$); \draw (V) -- ($(C)!(V)!(B)$);

  \end{tikzpicture}
%\end{center}

  \end{multicols}
\end{enumerate}

\noindent \begin{minipage}[b]{4.65in}
  \begin{enumerate}[start=4]
  \item The area of a rectangle is 168 square inches, and its
    perimeter is 62 inches. What is the product of the magnitudes of
    its diagonals?
  \end{enumerate}
\vspace*{2cm}
\end{minipage}
%
%
\hspace{0.1cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}

%Vertices A, B, C, and D are located.
\path (0,0) coordinate (A) (20:{7/8}) coordinate (B) ($(B) +(110:3)$) coordinate (C) ($(C) +(-160:{7/8})$) coordinate (D);
\draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- cycle;

%The diagonals are drawn.
\draw[dashed] (A) -- (C);
\draw[dashed] (B) -- (D);


%The length and width of the rectangle are typeset.
\node[anchor={20+90}, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($($(A)!1.5mm!-90:(B)$)!0.5!($(B)!1.5mm!90:(A)$)$){$w$};
\node[anchor={110+90}, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($($(B)!1.5mm!-90:(C)$)!0.5!($(C)!1.5mm!90:(B)$)$){$\ell$};

\end{tikzpicture}


\begin{enumerate}[start=5]
\item  If $a - b = 1$, $b - c = 2$, and $c - a = d$, evaluate $d$.
  \begin{multicols}{2}
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item $-3$
    \item $-1$
    \item $1$
    \item $3$
    \item $4$
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{multicols}


\item Evaluate the following logarithmic expressions.
  \begin{multicols}{3}
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item $\log_{2}8$
    \item $\log_{2}64$
    \item $\log_{2}\frac{1}{8}$
    \item $\log 10$
    \item $\log 100$
    \item $\log \left(\frac{1}{100}\right)$
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{multicols}

\item Solve the following logarithmic equations.
  \begin{multicols}{3}
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item $\log_{2}(3x + 7) = 3$
    \item $2\log(x + 1) = 16$
    \item $\log_{3}\left(\frac{x}{x - 4}\right) = 1$
    \item $\log(x + 1) - \log(x - 2) = 2$
    \item $\log\left(\frac{x + 1}{x - 2}\right) = 2$
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{multicols}

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

I left the TikZ code untouched.

**Edit**

If you want to be able to change the `itemsep` in a semi-automatic way, you could do the following:

```
\newlength{\adelyn}
\settoheight{\adelyn}{MM}% <-- use whatever you want here
\newcommand{\setitemsep}[1]{\settoheight{\adelyn}{#1}}
```

Then you would use it in the following way:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{% (
  leftmargin=*, itemsep=12pt, label={\textbf{\arabic*.)}}}

% set up length
\newlength{\adelyn}
% set default length
\settoheight{\adelyn}{MM}
% simplify process of setting length?
\newcommand{\setitemsep}[1]{\settoheight{\adelyn}{#1}}

\setlist[enumerate,2]{% (
  itemsep=1.25\adelyn,
  label={\textbf{\roman*.)}}, itemsep=8pt}


\begin{document}

\begin{center}\Large{\textbf{Review}}\end{center}\vskip0.3in

\begin{enumerate}
\item Express the following decimals as fractions.
  \begin{multicols}{4}
    % uses pre-defined length of \adelyn
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item $\frac{1}{8}$
    \item $\frac{1}{80}$
    \item $\frac{1}{800}$
    \item 1
    \item 10
    \item 100
    \item 1.75
    \item 1.075
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{multicols}

\item Express the following decimals as fractions
  \begin{multicols}{4}
    % reset 'base height'
    % \settoheight{\adelyn}{$\sqrt{b^2}$}
    \setitemsep{$\sqrt{b^2}$}

    \begin{enumerate}
    \item $\frac{1}{8}$
    \item $\frac{1}{80}$
    \item $\frac{1}{800}$
    \item 1
    \item 10
    \item 100
    \item 1.75
    \item 1.075
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{multicols}


\item Express the following decimals as fractions

  \begin{multicols}{4}

    % reset 'base height'
    % \settoheight{\adelyn}{$\frac{1}{8}$}
    \setitemsep{$\frac{1}{8}$}

    % reset how 'base height' is used
    \begin{enumerate}[itemsep=3\adelyn]
    \item $\frac{1}{8}$
    \item $\frac{1}{80}$
    \item $\frac{1}{800}$
    \item 1
    \item 10
    \item 100
    \item 1.75
    \item 1.075
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{multicols}


\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

This way you can change the 'base height' by changing the value of `\adelyn` and you can change the multiple of that height with `itemsep=<value>\adelyn`.

Comment: This code seems to be something that I can modify to get a format closer to what I want.  I see that you have `leftmargin=*` and `itemsep=12pt` for the arguments to `\setlist[enumerate,1]`.  I think that I remember seeing that  `leftmargin=*` means that the numbers will be typeset flush against the left margin.  Is `itemsep=12pt` telling `TeX` to skip a space equal to `12pt` from the right parenthesis to the text?  If this is the case, why did you use `8pt` for the second environment?

Comment: Also, I want the first column of the lower-case Roman numerals to be indented from the left margin.

Comment: There is one edit that I need to make to your code.  The choices in the first problem should have the inter-line spacing of text mode.  Here is another question that I have about `itemsep` to separate rows in the second level enumerate environment.  If the choices in a problem all involved square roots of integers,  the inter-line spacing of text mode would be too small and `12pt` would be too big. There is one edit that I need to make to your code.

Comment: Also, if  the choices in a problem all involved radical expressions involving letters like `a`, `c`, and `e`, the inter-line spacing of text would be fine, but if  the choices in a problem all involved radical expressions involving letters like `b` and `d`, more vertical spacing would be needed.  Can the value for `itemsep` be something like `1.2*\vphantom{$\sqrt{b}$}`?

Comment: I don't really understand your second last comment. As for your last comment: no, `itemsep` needs to be a length (e.g., `1cm`, `2.3ex`, `45pt`, and so on). You could measure the height of some text and then use that, but it seems like more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: Actually, I am looking to measure the height of text and multiply that by a `1.2`.  It is something like `\settoheight{\blah-blah}{$\sqrt{b}$}`.  Can you give me the appropriate code?

Comment: Do you mean: `\newlength{adelyn} \settoheight{\adelyn}{$\sqrt{b}$}` and then use in a specific environment: `\begin{enumerate}[itemsep={1.2\adelyn}]`? or (globally) `\setlist[enumerate,2]{itemsep=1.2\adelyn}`?

Comment: Yeah.  That is exactly what I am talking about.  I didn't know the syntax for it.  I will try to adapt it to my code.  (That is a novel use for my name.)    I would like to have such commands defined locally.  If I have a test or assignment with 25 questions, I don't want to have as many as 25 different names for heights of different boxes. If we replace `$\sqrt{b}$` with `$\frac{1}{8}$` in `\newlength{adelyn} \settoheight{\adelyn}{$\sqrt{b}$}`, how would you encode problem 2.)?

Comment: This gives me the correct syntax.  Thanks.  I didn't know the syntax for any of `\newlength`, `\setlength`,  and `\settoheight` commands.  After looking at  Digital Typography Using LaTeX by Apostolos Syropoulos, I can ask for clarification on your code. You have the commands `\newlength{\adelyn}` and  `\settoheight{\adelyn}{MM}` in your preamble, and you have `itemsep=1.25\adelyn` as an option to the second-level `enumerate` environment in the preamble.

Comment: Shouldn't  the default inter-line spacing in the typesetting of choices `i.)`, `ii.)`,  `iii.)`, ... be the same as the inter-line spacing in `text` mode?  (I guess you chose `MM` as a representative height of the tallest characters in ASCII.)  Compiling the code gives me spacing that is much bigger than inter-line spacing in `text` mode.

Comment: In case that all my choices are integers, decimals, or function values like `$\vert x - 1 \vert$`, `$sin(30^{\circ})$`, or `$\log(25)$`, I would like to have the same spacing as I have in `text` mode.

Comment: When the choices are integers or decimals as in the first problem of your second version, I want `\baselineskip` to be the inter-line spacing.  I encoded `\begin{enumerate}`
`\item` Express the following decimals as fractions. `\begin{multicols}{4}` `\settoheight{\adelyn}{\baselineskip}` `\begin{enumerate}` `\item 1` `\item 0.25` ... `\item 0.0625` `\end{enumerate}` `\end{multicols}` ... `\end{enumerate}` and got an error.   It said that I am missing a `}`.  Apparently, I can't use `\baselineskip` as a required argument to `\settoheight{\adelyn}`.

Comment: `itemsep=\baselineskip`.

Comment: Thanks.  For the same example, I want either `\baselineskip` or "a bit bigger than `\baselineskip` between the item and the choices.  How do I get either of these?

Comment: One more "thing."  I want the first column to be indented futher from the left margin.  How do I adjust that?  I don't see it in the code you provided.

Comment: These are the last two questions for this post.  I will approve your answer right afterwards.

Comment: Regarding the 'either': you must pick and set the value, it can't be both. If slightly bigger, use `itemsep=1.125\baselineskip` or whatever. (I don't think I understand what you mean by either.) For the margin, there are many options; one of these is `leftmargin`, which is set to the special value of `*` in the above example. Try something like `leftmargin=1cm` if you like, but remember that the `enumerate` environment is already set in a `multicols` environment, so the amount the `\item`s can be 'indented' is already constrained....

Comment: Yeah, I would like to remove some of these comments to make the post more helpful to other members.

Comment: In your second code, I think that I would like `1.125\baselineskip` between " Express the following decimals as fractions" and the choices, but I want `\baselineskip` separating the two rows of choices.

Comment: Yes, using something like `leftmargin=1.5cm` as an option to the second-level `enumerate` environment gave a nice display.

Comment: The text on the first-level is like `Express the following decimals as fractions` and `$\triangle\mathit{ABC}$ is a right triangle, ... `.  I think that I want the separation between such first-level text and second-level text, which consists of the choices, to be separated by `\baselineskip` or `1.25 \baselineskip`.

Comment: As always, you can do `\begin{enumerate}[<put options here>]` to give that specific list local options. However, you cannot easily change the spacing of each `\item` and the new list at the first level, so at a second level list you can use an option like `partopsep=1.25\baselineskip`. E.g., `\begin{enumerate}[partopskip=1.25\baselineskip]`. But this back and forth has gone on too long and I no longer know what on earth you're doing. It is probably best to ask a new question: take what you are using now based on this answer and ask a new question about the new problem.

Comment: Too late to change earlier comment, but I meant `topsep=<length>`, not `partopsep`....

Comment: I have tried `topsep=1.25\baselineskip`, `topsep=\baselineskip`, and `topsep=0.5\baselineskip` as options in the first-level `enumerate` environment for the first problem.  (This is where I have "Express the following decimals as fractions.")  There is no change in the displays.

Comment: OK.  I will ask a new question.  The display that I get using `text` mode and the `tabbing` environment gives me the inter-line spacing that I want for problems like the first problem in my post.

Comment: Please see "Encode into an `enumerate` environment (Version 2)" for clarification.

Comment: Maybe you could delete some of these comments too. We had a long back and forth that no one else is likely to benefit from....